# How can I make a POST request to the API with reference to the shell command of API?

Tags: android, shell, api, retrofit2, hypertrack

I am developing Android Application that uses API of [HyperTrack](https://www.hypertrack.io/)  (It is a web service that provides it’s APIs for the purpose of tracking Mobile Devices in real-time. It also provides functionality of Task and Driver handling in separate APIs.)

There is [Start a Trip](http://docs.hypertrack.io/docs/start-a-trip-in-android) Functionality that requires me to get Driver Key using shell command below:

```
Driver API:
curl -H "Authorization: token YOUR_SK_TOKEN" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -X POST \
 -d "{\"name\": \"Test driver\", \"vehicle_type\": \"car\"}" \
 https://app.hypertrack.io/api/v1/drivers/
```

This is how I am implementing these two APIs using Retrofit2 with following Request Interface:

```
public interface DriverRequestInterface
{
    @Headers ({
        "Authorization: token SECRET_KEY",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST ( "api/v1/drivers" )
    Call<DriverJSONResponse> getJSON (@Body DriverJSONResponse jsonResponse);
}
```

And Here is my DriverJSONResponse:

```
public class DriverJSONResponse
{
    /*
    JSON Object Fields
    @SerializedName ( "count" ) private int count;
    */

    @SerializedName ( "name" ) private String name;
    @SerializedName ( "vehicle_type" ) private String vehicleType;

    public DriverJSONResponse(String name, String vehicleType)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
    }

    /*
    Setter and Getter of JSON Object Fields
    public void setCount (int count) { this.count = count; }
    public int getCount () { return count; }
    */
}
```

So far with this, I am receiving a GET response, not POST. I am receiving JSON Object with list of Results but not able to post anything to API.

How can I make a POST request to the API with reference to the shell command of API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `DriverJSONResponse` class contains other fields along with `name` and `vehicle_type`, the code above passes following data to the `POST`:

```
{"count":0, "name":"Brian", "vehicle_type":"car", "results":[] }
```

which results in JSON Parsing Error.

So, use another model class for passing the `POST` parameters, like:

```
public class DriverJSON
{
    @SerializedName ( "name" ) private String name;
    @SerializedName ( "vehicle_type" ) private String vehicleType;

    public DriverJSON(String name, String vehicleType)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
    }

    public String getName () { return name; }
    public String getVehicleType () { return vehicleType; }
}
```

and pass this model class in the `RequestInterface` like:

```
public interface DriverRequestInterface
{
    @Headers ({
        "Authorization: token YOUR_SECRET_KEY",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST ( "api/v1/drivers/" )
    Call<DriverJSONResponse> getJSON (@Body DriverJSON json);
}
```

And don't forget to model your `DriverJSONResponse` in accordance with the JSON Object you expect to receive.